# What would have happened if Voldemort had won Priori Incantatem before Nagini had been decapitated?

Tags: harry-potter

As wielder of an elder wand that belonged to Harry, during Voldemort’s Last Stand, there are two instances of Priori Incantatem occurring, back to back.

Basically, the current order of events makes total sense. Since Nagini was the last horcrux, when the body died, the fragment of Voldemort’s soul locked in it was released. This disrupted the first instance of Priori Incantatem, and Voldemort was now significantly weaker than Harry – so Harry won. Naturally, the Elder Wand’s killing spell was reflected back on Voldemort because of Priori Incantatem outcome.

But, if Voldemort was just told by Harry that the Elder Wand wouldn’t work against Harry because it belonged to Harry, and was a wand that would win any duel for its master, why would Voldemort willingly try and continue to use it? This is doubly so, since after he had cast the killing spell on Harry once it had only torn Voldemort’s soul from Harry’s body – wouldn’t that even imply that the Elder Wand would realistically refuse almost any attempted direct harm against its owner?

Also, wouldn’t a first refusal of the Elder Wand to kill it’s own master also imply an additional refusal even if Voldemort had won either of the Priori Incantatem matches (in which case, the worst that could happen in this line of thinking is, Voldemort has Harry’s wand since Harry’s spell is Expelliarmus)?

Comment: Which 2 instances are you referring to? Priori incantatum is a phenomenon where wands that share a core fight each other. In the last few chapters of _The Deathly Hallows_ this never occurs! Harry no longer has his phoenix core wand. And Voldemort is using Dumbledore's wand.

Comment: @ash_k29 I believe the OP is referring to the movie version of events.

Comment: oh... Coz i just went ahead and re-read the last few chapters to refresh my memory, but no such reference.

Comment: I thought priori incantatum was the general name for when the wands produce the spells that meet in the middle distance and force a continuous stream of magic, where each duelist has to push the beam to the other end.

Comment: I thought it was clear that Voldemort was using the Elder wand at that point. And I'm talking about when it happened just before Voldemort dies, just as in the question I wrote in "Voldemort's Last Stand"

Comment: @AdamMiller -  there is no reference of any stream of magic and pushing in the very final fight.

Comment: I'm gonna go with *"Harry died, and with him died the hopes of the wizarding world. Thus began the era of a thousand years of darkness. The End"*.

Comment: “This is doubly so, since after he had cast the killing spell on Harry once it had only torn Voldemort’s soul from Harry’s body – wouldn’t that even imply that the Elder Wand would realistically refuse almost any attempted direct harm against its owner?” — Not really, no. As Dumbledore says, Harry had a _choice_. It was not the Elder Wand’s unwillingness that caused Harry to survive and the piece of Voldy’s soul to die; it was Harry’s choice. If he’d made a different choice, he would have been dead. (Of course, Voldemort didn’t know this, so the point is kind of moot.)

Comment: You're not making sense. That effect only happens when they share the same core! The Elder Wand's core is is Thestral. The wand Harry had at the time I can't recall but I'm almost certain it wasn't Thestral. And in any event the only time this happens is in Goblet of Fire. The film has that for drama but even then it didn't echo spells (and all that went with it) which means it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two things here.

**1. The happenings of the final of Deathly Hallows**

The movie version shows the final battle similar to the "Priori Incantatem" shown during *Goblet of Fire*. However, in the book version, this is not the case.

In the book version, the final battle is pretty simple. Quoting:

> Harry heard the high  voice shriek as he too yelled with his best hope to
>   the heavens, pointing Draco’s wand:  
>   *“Avada Kedavra!”
>
>   “Expelliarmus!”*
>
> The bang was like a cannon blast, and the golden flames that erupted
>   between  them, at the dead center of the circle they had been
>   treading, marked the point where the  spells collided.
> Harry saw
>   Voldemort’s green jet meet his own spell, saw the Elder Wand  fly
>   high, dark against the sunrise, spinning across the enchanted ceiling
>   like the head of  Nagini, **spinning through the air toward the master
>   it would not kill, who had come to  take full possession of it at
>   last.** 
> And Harry, with the unerring skill of the Seeker, caught  the
>   wand in his free hand as Voldemort fell backward, arms splayed, the
>   slit pupils of the  scarlet eyes rolling upward. 
> Tom Riddle hit the
>   floor with a mundane finality, his body  feeble and shrunken, the
>   white hands empty, the snakelike face vacant and unknowing. 
>  **Voldemort
>   was dead, killed by his own rebounding curse, and Harry stood with two
>   wands in his hand, staring down at his enemy’s shell.**

(**Emphasis mine**)

**2. Why did Voldemort go ahead even after what Harry said?**

Simple. Pure unadulterated ego. He believed that owning the wand was what mattered, and did not believe Harry’s (Dumbledore’s) version.

He believed that owning the wand made him invincible, and was arrogant enough to further believe that a teenager had no chance of beating him, that too with a half cooked theory.

Comment: Thank you, it's been years since I read the books, and I don't own them.

Comment: And in the film it's still not that effect. It's as you say similar. But only just. Many times in the films they meet each other like that if I remember right. But the only time it happens is when the wands share the same core and only once did it happen in the books (and films): Goblet of Fire.